# eslinting with react-hooks/exhaustive-deps doesn't work on Create React App

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, eslintrc

I have a trouble with react-hooks/exhaustive-deps on my create react app.

It's really weird. It worked once yesterday. Because I fixed dependency issues yesterday.
But after I changed something, but it doesn't work at all.
Unfortunately, I can't track what changes made.

I am really confused and had got trouble whenever setting up eslinting on react projects.

**package.json: you can check package versions.**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd -f .env.development craco start",
    
    "format": "prettier --write src/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}",
    "lint": "tsc --noEmit && eslint src/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix src/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}",
   
  },

"dependencies": {
...
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-scripts": "5.0.0",
"typescript": "^4.4.4",
"webpack": "^5.70.0"
}

"devDependencies": {
    ...

    "eslint": "^8.12.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.18.0",
}
```

**.eslintrc.js**

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: ['react', 'prettier', '@typescript-eslint', 'react-hooks'],
  extends: ['eslint:recommended', 'plugin:react/recommended', 'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended', 'prettier'],
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true,
    jest: true,
  },
  globals: {
    Atomics: 'readonly',
    SharedArrayBuffer: 'readonly',
  },
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: 'module',
    project: './tsconfig.json',
  },
  settings: {
    react: {
      createClass: 'createReactClass', // Regex for Component Factory to use,
      // default to "createReactClass"
      pragma: 'React', // Pragma to use, default to "React"
      fragment: 'Fragment', // Fragment to use (may be a property of <pragma>), default to "Fragment"
      version: 'detect', // React version. "detect" automatically picks the version you have installed.
      // You can also use `16.0`, `16.3`, etc, if you want to override the detected value.
      // It will default to "latest" and warn if missing, and to "detect" in the future
      flowVersion: '0.53', // Flow version
    },
    propWrapperFunctions: [
      'forbidExtraProps',
      { property: 'freeze', object: 'Object' },
      { property: 'myFavoriteWrapper' },
      // for rules that check exact prop wrappers
      { property: 'forbidExtraProps', exact: true },
    ],
    componentWrapperFunctions: [
      'observer', // `property`
      { property: 'styled' }, // `object` is optional
      { property: 'observer', object: 'Mobx' },
      { property: 'observer', object: '<pragma>' }, // sets `object` to whatever value `settings.react.pragma` is set to
    ],
    formComponents: [
      // Components used as alternatives to <form> for forms, eg. <Form endpoint={ url } />
      'CustomForm',
      { name: 'Form', formAttribute: 'endpoint' },
    ],
    linkComponents: [
      // Components used as alternatives to <a> for linking, eg. <Link to={ url } />
      'Hyperlink',
      { name: 'Link', linkAttribute: 'to' },
    ],
  },
  rules: {
    camelcase: 'off',
    'linebreak-style': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/naming-convention': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions': 'off',
    'unused-imports/no-unused-imports-ts': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires': 0,
    '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-shadow': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-ignore': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function': 'off',
    'no-use-before-define': 0,
    'no-case-declarations': 0,
    'no-constant-condition': 'off',
    'no-undef': 'off',
    'no-empty': 'off',
    'prettier/prettier': [
      'error',
      {
        endOfLine: 'auto',
        maxEOF: 4,
      },
    ],
    'react-hooks/rules-of-hooks': 'error',
    'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps': 'error',
  },
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```